# Execute Interactive Script on boot and display to default tty attached monitor screen

Tags: linux, bash, startup, tty

I have configured my Centos 6 to autologin on every boot.

I have modified the /etc/init/tty.conf to achieve this, this works fine.

content of /etc/init/tty.conf

```
stop on runlevel [S016]

respawn
instance $TTY
#exec /sbin/mingetty $TTY
exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin root $TTY
usage 'tty TTY=/dev/ttyX  - where X is console id'
```

Then I have configured my ~/.bash_profile to run a script. See below the content.

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH


echo "This is one time" >/tmp/one.txt
```

As you can see above I have echo'd text to a file /tmp/one.txt,
Expected text in the file should appear only one time. But for some reason this script is executed 3 times .

If I tail -f /tmp/one.txt following appears in /tmp/one.txt.  It shows that the script is executed 3 times.

```
tail -f /netboot/tmp/one.txt
This is one time
tail: /netboot/tmp/one.txt: file truncated
This is one time
tail: /netboot/tmp/one.txt: file truncated
This is one time
tail: /netboot/tmp/one.txt: file truncated
This is one time
```

What can I do to prevent it from executing it multiple times, I just want this to run once that's all.

Thanks for reading this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove respawn instance $TTY from /etc/init/tty.conf file.

Before fixing /etc/init/tty.conf looks like this.

```
stop on runlevel [S016]

respawn
instance $TTY
#exec /sbin/mingetty $TTY
exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin root $TTY
usage 'tty TTY=/dev/ttyX  - where X is console id'
```

After fixing the problem. /etc/init/tty.conf looks like this.

```
stop on runlevel [S016]


exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin root $TTY
usage 'tty TTY=/dev/ttyX  - where X is console id'
```

This has fix the problem I have explain above.